# Storing db value into php array with while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, mysqli

I am wanting to search through AdvInfo table and store the primary keys if Unit = Child.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM AdvInfo WHERE Unit = Child");     
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 {

$childhbc = array_merge($childhbc, $row[0]);
echo $childhbc[0];
 }
```

Comment: can you echoing your select query ?

Comment: No. echoing $childhbc also returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) should be an array. But to quote the documentation:

> [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) [...] returns an array of strings that corresponds
> to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

In your code, `$row` is an *array*. `$row[0]` is a *string*.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $childhbc = array_merge($childhbc, $row);
    echo $childhbc[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, man

```
$childhbc = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM AdvInfo WHERE Unit = Child");     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $childhbc[] = $row[0];
}
```

The less intricate words you use - the better your program works